# How to implement dynamic layout columns by using the `content_for?` method?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby on Rails 3. I would like to render a layout by using the `content_for?` method in order to "conditionally" generate HTML code with proper CSS properties. That is, I would like to implement a layout with the following features:

- if `content_for` a left column is present then the layout has 2 columns (a *left column* with fixed width and a *content column* with the remaining width);
- if `content_for` a left column is *not* present then the layout has 1 column (a *content column* with full width).

How can I implement it inside the `/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` file? Have you some advices?

*Note*: Hopefully, I am looking for a sample implementation of the layout (including also Ruby on Rails methods, HTML and CSS code).

---

**Bonus**: *Inside* the *content column* block I would like to "conditionally" display a *right column* if `content_for` the right column is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use adjacent (`+`) or subsequent (`~`) sibling selectors to conditionally apply a margin to your content column based on whether or not the left column is visible.

For your bonus question, you should put the content of content column inside an inner wrap div, and then use the `:nth-last-child` to check whether or not the right column is visible and conditionally apply a margin there as well:

**CSS**:

```
.page {
  position: relative;
}

.page .left-column {
  background: lavender;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 180px;
}

.page .content-column { background: orange; }

.page .content-column > .inner-wrap { background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3); }

.page .left-column + .content-column {
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.page .content-column .right-column {
  background: lime; 
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 90px;
}

.page .content-column > .inner-wrap:nth-last-child(2) {
  margin-right: 100px;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="page">

  <% if content_for?(:left_column) %>
    <div class="left-column">
      <%= yield(:left_column) %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="content-column">
    <div class="inner-wrap">
      <%= yield(:content_column) %>
    </div>

    <% if content_for?(:right_column) %>
      <div class="right-column">
        <%= yield(:right_column) %>
      </div> 
    <% end %>          
  </div>

</div>
```

Preview of rendered layout: http://jsbin.com/icurey/8/edit

Comment: Thank you, but is the HTML code to much "hacked"? That is, there is a more "correct" way to make the same?

Comment: Well actually, using the `+` (or `~`) combinator in the last CSS ruleset, there is no need to have the opening tag for your content column inside the if-else - you may put a single opening tag outside the if-else and rely on the CSS to apply the margin iff there is a left column.  I have only used if-else to show what you could do if you wanted to give it different classes for full/partial width. Try to take out those `full-width` and `partial-width` classes in the jsbin and see how it still works!

Comment: I've removed the if-else stuff in my answer as it seems superfluous to what you want anyway.  So you can skip the "hacky" markup and use CSS entirely instead.

Comment: Why are you using CSS `position: relative`, `position: absolute`, `left: 0`, `top: 0`, ... and CSS sibling? *Is it possible to simplify CSS statements?* For example, the same could be accomplished without using "strict" sibling, but with `float` and similar properties?

Comment: Because I prefer having more control, but you can certainly use float as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna check `content_for?`, which returns `true` if content was yielded for the given argument. See [`content_for?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for-3F)

Comment: I know the `content_for?` method. I am looking for a "working" *code* related also to HTML and CSS.

Comment: After an hour and a half of trying (without success), I came to the conclusion that it was better to ask some help (otherwise, what would be the reason for existence of Stackoverflow?!). I think that it is quite easy for some expert on the Web to implement that layout (in my case, it is a so simple matter for someone)... *P.S.*: "Basically" speaking, I always hope that *there are many generous souls*.